# VBA Troubles with removing .select from code

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to remove the .Select from my code because I found out recently it's not really an efficient way to do things, but i can't get this piece of code to work.

The data I am pasting comes from another program so it is on the clipboard

My current code(which works):

```
Range("A3:A3").Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False
```

I have been trying to fix it in two ways, but both give errors.
Option 1:

```
Worksheets("Orders").Range("A3").PasteSpecial _
Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayasIcon:=False
```

Option 2:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ps = Sheets("Orders")

With ps.Range("A3")
    .PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
   False
End With
```

Both give "application defined or object defined error" so I'm doing something wrong, i just can't figure out where the wrong part is.

Comment: I give you an answer below, but I can see also that you declare "ws" for the worksheet but you set "ps".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Sheets("Orders")
Ws.Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Comment: How does this differ, in any meaningful way, to the other answers already given? In fact, if you follow the progression of the question you'll realise that this solution doesn't work for OP.

Comment: You would think that, and yet this works exactly as i intended

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** based on comments

As you are pasting from the clipboard directly, not from another range, you will need the [`Worksheet.PasteSpecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-pastespecial-method-excel) version, rather than [`Range.PasteSpecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel).

```
Sub PasteFromClipboard() 
    '
    'code which loads clipboard
    '
    With Worksheets("Orders")
        .Activate 'activate the worksheet so that you can select a range on this sheet
        .Range("A3").Select        
        .PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayasIcon:=False 
    End With   
End Sub
```

Comment: You're right, I did not have the code from where I copied it because there isn't any. The data is copied from a web page so the data is on the clipboard

Comment: @perbrethil, I see.. I've updated my answer. Let me know if that works for you now :)

Comment: Though this is a more elegant version of my current code (and it works!), my purpose was to remove the .select from my code with the purpose i could run it from another tab in my workbook without the code having to switch tabs back and forth, is this possible?

Comment: @perbrethil, because you are not specifying where on the worksheet to paste the data when you use Sheet.PasteSpecial you need to specify beforehand by selecting the range. If you don't mind where the data is pasted then remove the `.Select`, otherwise you will have to switch tabs I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

try to declare your workbook :

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
```

and after your worksheet :

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Orders")
```

and past :

```
ws.Range("a3").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Comment: Good news is the error is gone, bad news another one popped up. If I run the code (changed the last part into "ws.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
   False") it highlights the -Format:="Text"- part and give Named argument not found

Comment: @perbrethil, that is because Range.PasteSpecial doesn't have the *Format* named argument. Only Worksheet.PasteSpecial has that named argument

Comment: @perbrethil I edited the answer. Format:="Text" is remplaced by "xlValues"

Answer (score 0):

For the first option you forgot the ***""***

This should work:

```
Worksheets("Orders").Range("A3").PasteSpecial _
Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayasIcon:=False
```

For the second option change *ps* in *ws* as JC Guidicelli said.